# how to remove the square brackets that csv.writer.writerow create

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm using csv.writer.writerow to write multiple parameters: `chromosome.weight_height, chromosome.weight_holes, chromosome.weight_bumpiness, chromosome.weight_line_clear`
for each row inside a csv file, the problem is that write the correct values but with the square brackets, and i don't want this.
Is there a way to remove the brackets?

```
def write_generation_to_file(generation_number, population):
    with open(configuration.WEIGHTS_FILES_FOLDER + "generation_" + str(generation_number) + "_weights.csv", 'w',
              newline='') as file:
        for chromosome in population:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow([chromosome.weight_height, chromosome.weight_holes, chromosome.weight_bumpiness,
                             chromosome.weight_line_clear])
```

[image: Image of the problem]

EDIT 1:

Those are some example of the parameters that i give to the function.
As i know numpy.random.uniform return only one element.
If i try to do `chromosome.weight_height[0]`, for example, it throw exception

```
weight_height = numpy.random.uniform(-2,2)
weight_holes = numpy.random.uniform(-2,2)
weight_bumpiness = numpy.random.uniform(-2,2)
weight_line_clear = numpy.random.uniform(-2,2)
```

Comment: is chromeosome.weight_heigt an array? Then try to cast it as an int

Comment: No, all the parameters are float

Comment: Can you try specifying delimiter and quotechar in csv.writer?

Comment: Nothing change since the delimiter and the quotechar are the same as the default ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its likely that `weight_height`, `weight_holes` etc are actually lists with a single element in them. Try giving the first element in the list during the `writerow` and see if that fixes it. E.g:

```py
writer.writerow([chromosome.weight_height[0], chromosome.weight_holes[0], chromosome.weight_bumpiness[0], chromosome.weight_line_clear[0]])
```

This may or may not solve your problem as my answer is based on the assumption that these values are single element lists.

Comment: As i said in the comment before, the parameters are all float. I will update the question with an edit that show it

Comment: @Fanto hmm, thats odd. I'm not sure then. On an unrelated note, you should probably move `writer = csv.writer(file)` out of the for loop as there is no reason to redeclare it each time you iterate.

Comment: Thanks for making me noticing it, didn't see it until now!